# how send to google ping after add new post

Tags: seo

I want to tell Google that i add a new post on my site. How to announce Google that index my page again? 
I know that it is possible to index the site map, but as a possible re-indexed from a single post (page)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 22):

after adding your post. change the **last modified date** of updated pages in your sitemap, (if you are using WordPress or Blogspot, you can use sitemap plugins to do this automatically).

then **resubmit the sitemap in Webmaster Tools (both Bing and Google)**

alternatively try the following method to tell search engines that you have updated your website

**Ping Google Bot**

type following URL in address bar of your browser

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=[your sitemap web address]
```

for example:

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http://www.example.com/sitemap-file.xml
```

**Ping Bing Bot**

type following URL in address bar of your browser

```
http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=[your sitemap web address]
```

for example:

```
http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=http://www.exmaple.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Without typing anything, this also works with a post request? Can I, for example, use jquery to resent my sitemap to bing and/or google and or use curl?

Comment: This is very useful.  Do we need to ping yahoo as well?

Comment: Yahoo and Bing Webmaster are merged so when you add/ping sitemap to Bing it's automatically reflect to yahoo also.

Comment: should be the accepted answer as it's even suggested by [google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669?hl=en#resubmit), at least

Comment: Google's Specification (2019) for pinging is: `http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=<full_URL_of_sitemap>` ([Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en))

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Google automatically figures out frequency of your updates. If you update your site more often then google will check it more often.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is submit a sitemap to Google every time you update your site. I dont think you can actully tell them to re-index. There are add-ons for popular CMS's and Blog hosting software that will auto-submit site maps.

Comment: I think about that, but my site map is big (~1 mb).

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your new post to google blog search via xml-prc pings.

http://blogsearch.google.com/ping/RPC2

http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/weblogsCom.html

It seems google crawls the page few seconds after ping.